# jQuery ajax, .each and ajax again

Tags: jquery

No this is not another question about how to use AJAX.

Why does this not work for me ?

What the code should do:

1. When a button is clicked, it should send a Title and a User id to a PHP file, which should insert that in the database.
2. Then it should make a `.each` on all elements inside a div, and send each of them to a PHP file, which should insert them to the database.
3. and finally it should redirect.

I get the first alert with "first" but i don't get the one with "second" and nothing is inserted in the database.

My previous code worked fine with inserting, and it does the same, just not as advanced and without the redirect function

my code:

```
$('#tabCreateButton').click(function () {
    alert("first"); //checking for click

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", url: "/page/newtab.php", data: "action=newtitle&tabname=" + tabname + "&bid=" + brugerid,
        complete: function (data) {
            alert("second"); //checking for response
            var tabid = $(data.responseText);

            var XHRs = [];

            $('#tabCurrentFriends > .dragFriend').each(function () {
                var friendid = $(this).data('rowid');
                XHRs.push($.ajax({
                    type: "POST", url: "page/newtab.php", data: "action=newtab&tabid=" + tabid + "&bid=" + brugerid + "&fid=" + friendid,
                    complete: function (data) {
                    }
                }));
            });

            $.when(XHRs).then(function () {
                alert("third"); //should redirect here.
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: shouldn't $(data.responseText); just be data.responseText;?

Comment: @TerryR `$.when` with array of deferred objects is working.

Comment: @TerryR wow thanks alot! thats a very helpfull tool! :) 
it gives me the error that tabname is not defined i will look at it and return if it still aint working :) 
thanks alot!

Comment: success! thanks for the tip @TerryR :)

Comment: Sure thing, chances are `brugerid` is also not defined then since it looks like the same scope of variable.

Comment: some of the variables are defined earlier in the script :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have an XHR error or a Javascript error you are not seeing.

You can check for these errors using Chrome's built in debugger (F12 --> Network --> XHR) or Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `complete:` with `success:` and `error:`, each with a unique callback function that you can use to check for XHR errors (if any).

Comment: i have always used complete: without problems :) 
but unfortunately this wouldn't help ether